# Is there a way to bind a variable that enumerates alternative property paths in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

Suppose I have the following alternative property path:

```
select *
where{
?sub :p1|:p2 ?ob
}
```

How can I bind a third variable (?map) which keeps track of what path (:p1 or :p2) was taken for each match?

If this is impossible is there another way to enumerate paths?

I am intentionally avoiding expanding this predicate as a UNION because in real life my pattern includes multiple property paths and UNIONS would make the query ridiculously long.

edit: clarify in response to comments, I am not looking for graph traversal, just pairs of nodes with properties linking them

Answer (score 0):

can just add the predicate variable explicitly:

```
select *
where{
?sub :p1|:p2 ?ob .
?sub ?pred ?ob .
}
```

Sandboxed demos:

[answer](http://sparql-playground.sib.swiss/?query=%0ASELECT%20*%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%3Fs%20tto:pet%7Ctto:weight%20%3Fo%20.%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%7D%0A%0A%23%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0A%23Values%20%3Fp%20%7Btto:pet%20tto:weight%7D%7D%0A%20%20%0A%0ALIMIT%2010&output=html)

[comment suggestion (equivalent)](http://sparql-playground.sib.swiss/?query=%0ASELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%23%3Fs%20tto:pet%7Ctto:weight%20%3Fo%20.%0A%23%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0AValues%20%3Fp%20%7Btto:pet%20tto:weight%7D%7D%0A%20%20%0A%0ALIMIT%2010&output=html)

Comment: Test on `:a :p1 :b; :p2 :b; :p3 :b.`.

Comment: That answer can't be correct. As I always tell people, sparql is not a graph traversal language. Your query will just return all properties between two nodes having either p1 or p2 as connection. If this is all you need, ok. If not, you need better examples. Did you try `Select ?s ?p ?o {Values ?p {:p1 :p2} ?s ?p ?o}`

Comment: Thanks, yes this is just for getting pairs of nodes with property linking them